# javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for PropertiesLoginModule

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, jaas, apache-tomee

I am having some troubles  while starting a JAAS configured TomEE session (see log at the bottom of page).
To configure TomEE for using JAAS, I used [this guide](http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-jaas.html).
So here my configuration:

**server.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- TomEE plugin for Tomcat -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
    <!--
    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
         connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
         described in the APR documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
          <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" appName="PropertiesLoginModule"
          userClassNames="org.apache.openejb.core.security.AbstractSecurityService$User"
          roleClassNames="org.apache.openejb.core.security.AbstractSecurityService$Group"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

**login.conf**

```
PropertiesLogin {
    org.apache.openejb.core.security.jaas.PropertiesLoginModule required
    Debug=false
    UsersFile="users.properties"
    GroupsFile="groups.properties";
};
```

And this is the string I use to start TomEE:

```
sh startup.sh -Djava.security.auth.login.config=$CATALINA_BASE/conf/login.config
```

[here is the **catalina log**](http://pastebin.com/hbKm012s)

Comment: Why are you enclosing your PropertiesLoginModule <Realm> node inside the <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm"> ... </Realm> element?

Comment: @tmarwen Putting it on the root of server.xml makes the web application not starting

Comment: No not on the root of server descriptor but it should be under <Engine> tag not under <Realm> tag.
Please update you file and retest.

Comment: @tmarwen I have tried to use the following two server.xml files but both of them does not work, resulting in a `HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception`
1) http://pastebin.com/TZxVjTFi   2) http://pastebin.com/Nfj1NpHk

Comment: This mainly relate to your servlet descriptor, please paste the whole stack trace when starting with [second configuration](http://pastebin.com/Nfj1NpHk).

Comment: catalina.out http://pastebin.com/VWmPZKUr http 500 logs http://pastebin.com/p3rXSwEC

Comment: Try with the following [server.xml](http://pastebin.com/V8FRmd47)

Comment: @tmarwen it works, but what about the other removed realm entries?
You can fill an answer so I can give you the green mark.

Comment: There is no need to worry about the other realms since you can add in or remove as many realms as you want.
Take a look at some readings about realms and those that used to be registered into your server descriptor, e.g. the `<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>` is a well-known one which aims to define a realm with in-memory registered users under tomcat-users.xml file, basic but not high scale configuration :)
I've added an answer so it's made viewble for further visits.

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that your `<Realm>` is enclosed under the `<Engine>` tag of the server descriptor. It should look like the following:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
  ...
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" appName="PropertiesLoginModule"
     userClassNames="org.apache.openejb.core.security.AbstractSecurityService$User"
     roleClassNames="org.apache.openejb.core.security.AbstractSecurityService$Group">
  </Realm>
  ...
</Engine>
```

Then make sure that the `SecurityListener` and `OpenEJBListenre` are registered with following statements:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  ...
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.tomee.loader.OpenEJBListener" />
  ...
</Server>
```

Comment: Unluckly I am still experiencing the trouble and I haven't made any changes to the project since last time I tried.

Comment: You mentionnee that is was already resolved with suggested descriptor!

Answer (score 1):

first the appName attribute in the server.xml must match an existing entry in jaas.config file.
Currently, the appName is PropertiesLoginModule, whereas in jaas.config, you have PropertiesLogin. That is why the JAAS Realm cannot find the module.

If not set, Tomcat uses 'tomcat' as appName.
So either change the attr value or the login module app name in jaas.config.

Try that instead

```
  <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
       via a brute-force attack -->
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
    <!-- first try the LDAP authentication and fallback to tomcat-users.xml -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm"
           appName="PropertiesLogin"
           userClassNames="org.apache.openejb.core.security.jaas.UserPrincipal,
           com.sun.security.auth.LdapPrincipal"
           roleClassNames="org.apache.openejb.core.security.jaas.GroupPrincipal"/>

    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
         resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
         that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
         available for use by the Realm.  -->
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
           resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

  </Realm>
```

Regards,
Jean-Louis

Comment: My application's name is `LAI_pezzi_Login` so ideally I should change the server.xml in that way http://pastebin.com/Uvqk0kuZ and the login.conf in that other way http://pastebin.com/7zqqCnjh  Is it correct? If yes, this did not solve the problem